# How to automatically fill in www. and .com in chrome in Mac - equivalent of Ctrl+enter in Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, mac

In windows it was possible to just type the domain name and then press Ctrl+enter which resulted in the www. and .com prefix and suffix being added automatically. Is there an equivalent on the Mac?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Mac OS X Google chrome you can use the same thing using in windows `Control+enter`.